# UITableViewController not calling the delegate methods

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uitableview

I want to show a tableViewController in a popover, Created TableViewController like this.

```
@interface ContentViewController :UITableViewController{

}
@end

@implementation ContentViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])) {
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(100,400);

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", [indexPath row]]; 
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}
```

From another ViewController i am calling this tableViewController in a popOver as following.

```
UIViewController *contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc]    initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.popoverController = [[popoverClass alloc]    initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] ;
self.popoverController.delegate = self;
CGRect rect = btn.frame;
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

When i am allocating the ContentViewController with init statement the tableView delegate methods are not calling and in the popOver nothing is created.

How to make this delegate methods to call.

Comment: Did you Set the delegate dude  ??

Comment: just set the delegate & datasource of tableView in `viewDidLoad` of `ContentViewController`

Comment: ContentViewController's super class is UITableViewController so no need of setting delegates again. with this statement it has to call all the delegate methods (self = [super initWithStyle:style]), Any how i wrote delegates in viewDidLoad but no use.

Comment: if your uitableview is properly instantiated, i.e. self.tableview != nil, then try to call [self.tableview reloadData]; method in your viewDidLoad of contentviewcontroller

Comment: btw what is popoverClass? try to alloc your popoverController with UIPopoverController class

Comment: popoverClass is custom popOverController for Iphone,"wepopovercontroller" available at https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Answer (score 1):

Check with your delegate and datasource where it get assign.

If your `ContentViewController` have nib file means, just track datasource and delegate to your Files Owner. Otherwise Overright your `initWithStyle` method by set delegate and datasource as below.

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

And tell to contentViewController will implement tableview controller delegate and datasource method like

```
@interface ContentViewController :UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

}
@end
```